# Change a value in embedded xlsx with apache poi

Tags: java, excel, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

I tried to change a value of a xlsx-file which is embedded in a docx-file with apache poi. Sadly, I havent found a proper solution to this problem. After running my program, the new created docx-file with the embedded xlsx-table hasnt changed.
Here is what I have tried so far:

```
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("old.docx");
 XWPFDocument xdoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
     System.out.println(xdoc.getAllEmbedds().get(0));
     File file2 = new File("new.docx");
     
     for (PackagePart pPart : xdoc.getAllEmbedds()) {
        String contentType = pPart.getContentType();
       
        // Excel Workbook - OpenXML file format
        if (contentType.equals("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")) {
            XSSFWorkbook embeddedWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(pPart.getInputStream());
            XSSFSheet sheet = embeddedWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
            sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).setCellValue("someValue"); //change value here
            embeddedWorkbook.write(pPart.getOutputStream());
        }
    }
    xdoc.write(new FileOutputStream(file2));
```

any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: What happens if you skip the XWPF part, and only work at the OPCPackage level?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that this will be possible with fulfillment of all wishes. In fact, the embedded `XSSFWorkbook` is updated. But what you see if you open the `new.docx` is not the `XSSFWorkbook` but a `EMF` picture of it. This picture will only be updated if you doubleclick it to opening the embedded `XSSFWorkbook` and then click outside it to close it again.

Some other posts suggest that it will be updated while opening the `Word` file if this `EMF` picture is not actually within the `ZIP` archive. But it will not.

Try:

```
  for (PackagePart pPart : xdoc.getPackage().getPartsByName(Pattern.compile(".*emf$"))) {
    System.out.println(pPart.getPartName());
    //xdoc.getPackage().removePartRecursive(pPart.getPartName());
    xdoc.getPackage().removePart(pPart.getPartName());
  }
```

So the "solution" would be, new creating a `EMF` snapshot picture form the updated `XSSFWorkbook` and replace the old  `EMF` picture with this new one. Not really possible in my opinion.

Seems as if the program routine for creating the `EMF` snapshot picture is part of the `Word` application if the embedded `XSSFWorkbook` is closed. But it is not part of `apache-poi` until now. And of course it is not part of the `XML` program routines.

Answer (score 0):

Setting this before saving the document:

```
// ask user to refresh fields upon opening the document
document.enforceUpdateFields();
```

updates the Excel preview image for me, when the user opens the file and accepts field update by clicking Yes.