# Embedded Excel Error in Word. Unable to see the data, But can see when double clicked

Tags: excel, ms-word, apache-poi

This is my requirement : 
I need to read a excel file and print the matching data in an embedded excel sheet in word.
I am able to read and write it but unable to see the changes without double clicking the sheet in word.

Is there any way so that I don't have to double click on the embedded sheet to see the data?

NOTE : I am using POI for reading the excel.

Thanks

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999527/change-a-value-in-embedded-xlsx-with-apache-poi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change a value in embedded xlsx with apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999527/change-a-value-in-embedded-xlsx-with-apache-poi)